# Change label of Select Component using material ui react

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm working on material ui react storybook . I want user to change the label , Below is what i have tried with that  the Input Label is not taking any value which making select component without any label. I cannot use TextField , because i'm working on select component. I have to achieve this with the Input Label. Thanks

[image: Input looks as so ..]

```
 import React from "react";
    import { Theme, useTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";
    import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
    import InputLabel from "@mui/material/InputLabel";
    import MenuItem from "@mui/material/MenuItem";
    import FormControl from "@mui/material/FormControl";
    import Select, { SelectChangeEvent } from "@mui/material/Select";
    
    const age = ["Ten", "Twenty", "Thirty"];
    export const SelectBa = ({}) => {
      const theme = useTheme();
      const [personName, setPersonName] = React.useState([]);
    
      const handleChange = (event: SelectChangeEvent<typeof personName>) => {
        const {
          target: { value }
        } = event;
        setPersonName(typeof value === "string" ? value.split(",") : value);
      };
    
      return (
        <div>
          <FormControl sx={{ m: 1, width: 300 }} size={size}>
            <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">{selectname.map((label) => { label })}</InputLabel>
            <Select
              labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
              id="demo-simple-select"
              value={personName}
              onChange={handleChange}
              input={<OutlinedInput label="Name" />}
            >
              {age.map((age) => (
                <MenuItem
                  key={age}
                  value={age}
                  style={getStyles(age, personName, theme)}
                >
                  {age}
                </MenuItem>
              ))}
            </Select>
          </FormControl>
        </div>
      );
    };
    
    export default SelectBa;


stories.js

export const Selectde = SelectBa.bind({});
SelectDefault.args = {    
    selectname: [{ label: 'Select' }],

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `return` keyword in `{}`

```
<InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">
      {selectname.map((item) => { return item.label })}
</InputLabel>
```

Comment: i'm getting below error if i use return 
"Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {label}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead."

Comment: should i define Item ? if yes where ?

Comment: i have edited again

Comment: Thanks a lot. it did work :) I wasted whole day on this . thanks a lot